# All the hashtags in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pragma

I'm trying to learn iOS development (Objective-C) and I want to know what all the weird little "hashtags" or "pound symbols" mean. For example...

- `#import` is used to import a header file, and can be used in either of the following syntaxes (first is for a class in your project and second is by imported framework)

  `#import "PREFIX-SomeClass.h"`

  `#import <SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h>`
- `#pragma`, that I know, can have arguments appended to it that do IDE-specific stuff. The only function I know of is `#pragma mark`, and that puts a little mark in the compiler you can refer back to later. (It is worth noting that these two examples below do different things, **due to the hyphen**:)

  `#pragma mark Refer back to this later, but don't put a horizontal divider before it.`

  `#pragma mark - This groups a set of functions with a horizontal divider.`

Any idea what the rest of these functions are? Can somebody at least give me a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called preprocessor directives.

A list of them for clang (the native OSX compiler) can be found at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Index-of-Directives.html#Index-of-Directives

Comment: So this code runs on the compiler before it runs on the physical device?

Comment: No, the compiler works in stages. The first stage is pre processing. It happens before processing the actual source code. For instance, #include lines are replaced by the contents of the file included.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know that! Thank you for that bit of info!